# Model: Accounts -> Users -> Posts .. how to get all posts for an account? (the Rails way)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following (simplified) model:

```
Accounts:
- id
- name

Users: (belongs to Accounts)
- id
- account_id
- name

Posts: (belongs to Users)
- id
- user_id
- title
- body
```

Is something like this the best way to fetch posts for an account?

```
posts = []
account.users.each do |user|
  posts.merge(user.posts)
end
posts.sort_by_created_at
```

In the past I would probably put an account_id in the Posts table coz it seems like a lot of database queries if there are many Users, I worry about performance - and synchronization issues have two account_ids (Users and then Posts, when Account and Posts are already linked by User:user_id -> Posts:account_id -> account). Would appreciate any advice on this matter. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

in account.rb

```
has_many :posts, :through => :users
```

Then to fetch all the posts associated with an account

```
account.posts.each do |post|
  # your code
end
```

Now to reduce the no. of database queries you can join tables, when fetching account data from database you can use this query

```
account = Account.where(your_condition).includes(:posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with 'has_many through' is that it uses a join internally. Its not appropriate to use join everywhere. example scenario: If you have thousands of accounts each with thousands of users each with thousands of posts, the join table would contain 1000 * 1000 records.

I would suggest another approach.

```
def posts
  Post.where(user_id: users.pluck(:id))
end
```

the pluck method retrieves only the specified field from the database and not the entire record. The above method will fire 2 queries: 1) to retrieve all user ids 2) to retrieve posts where user_id is in the specified array of ids.

The above method can be used on any Account object as

```
@account.posts
```